# Linking a collection of buttons to a collection of labels

Tags: c#, wpf

I am reading in an XML file and using it to populate a WPF Form. Each entry in the XML file is used to create a button and a label.

The problem I am having is associating the button with the label:

Here is my code:

```
// Loop through Backups
foreach (var back in backups)
{
    // Create Wrap Panel
    myWrapPanel = new WrapPanel();
    //myWrapPanel.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
    myWrapPanel.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
    myWrapPanel.Width = 600;
    myWrapPanel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    myWrapPanel.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;

    // **************************************
    // Add Controls to Wrap Panel
    // **************************************
    // Backup Source
    System.Windows.Controls.Button btnBackupSource = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
    btnBackupSource.Content = "Source";
    btnBackupSource.Height = 25;
    btnBackupSource.Width = 75;
    btnBackupSource.Click += btnBackupSource_Click;
    btnBackupSource.Name = "btnBackupSource";
    myWrapPanel.Children.Add(btnBackupSource);

    System.Windows.Controls.Label lblBackupSource = new System.Windows.Controls.Label();
    lblBackupSource.Height = 25;
    lblBackupSource.Width = 461;
    lblBackupSource.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    lblBackupSource.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    lblBackupSource.Name = "lblBackupSource";
    lblBackupSource.Content = "";
    myWrapPanel.Children.Add(lblBackupSource);
```

The button and labels are created OK but I am struggling to associate them with each other. For example when a button is pressed the result needs to come up in the individual label which is associated with the button.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be very welcome!

What I have currently got is each button updating a single label:

```
private void btnBackupSource_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SourceFolderBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        // Allow users to creating new folders and default to the my documents folder.
        SourceFolderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        SourceFolderBrowser.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal;

        SourceFolderBrowser.ShowDialog();

        label2.Content = SourceFolderBrowser.SelectedPath;
    }
```

However what I am trying to do is get each button to update its associated label.

Comment: So when you click the button you want "his" lable to be visible, am I right?

Comment: Can't you create a `UserControl` that contains the button and the label and create dynamically that?

Comment: Yes. When you click the button I want the label set to a value that the button gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for you:

Store the label you want to associate with the button in the button's `Tag` property like this:

```
btnBackupSource.Tag = lblBackupSource;
```

Later when you to do something in the wired up `btnBackupSource_Click` you can do it like this:

```
var button = sender as Button;
var label = button.Tag as Label;
label.Text = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier by creating a DataTemplate and setting the ListBox.ItemTemplate to use the DataTemplate.

That way you do not have to create all the controls in code and need to wire up the button and label only once (preferably by databinding).

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="backupView">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="{Binding BackupName}"/>
            <Button Content="Source" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource backupView}"/>
```

In code you would need to create a class (Backup?) with the property Name and a DoSomethingCommand. This command would modify the Name of the Backup and that would automatically being passed on to the view.